# How to make pressed button effect AndEngine?

Tags: android, button, andengine

I want to make my button when pressed it show pressed effect. I already try this but somehow it fail.

Here's my code:

```
Sprite btnMultiPLayer = new ButtonSprite(CAMERA_WIDTH/2-BtnMultiPlayerUpITextureRegion.getWidth()/2, 300,   BtnMultiPlayerUpITextureRegion,BtnMultiPlayerDownITextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager(), new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ButtonSprite pButtonSprite, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
        Intent z = new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, PlayerIdentity.class);
        startActivity(z);            
    }
});
mMainScene.registerTouchArea(btnMultiPLayer);
mMainScene.attachChild(btnMultiPLayer);
mMainScene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
```

Since I have not enough reputation I can't post my broken menu directly.

http://imageshack.com/a/img540/5185/Ejs3WV.jpg

Could someone help me?
I'm developing in Android using Eclipse and AndEngine.

Answer (score 1):

The way to go with this is with [TiledSprite](http://www.matim-dev.com/tiledsprite--animatedsprite.html). Basically, it is a sprite that can switch between different parts of a single image on demand. For example, consider the following image: 
[image: Tiled sprite example]

By using `TiledSprite`, this image would be split into two "tiles"- i.e., parts. The sprite that will contain this image would be set by default to show tile 0 (in our case the left part), but when pressed, it'll switch to tile 1 (the right part) hence giving a *pressed effect button*. The outline of the code would be something like this:

```
TiledSprite tsprite = new TiledSprite(0,0,tiledregion,getVertexBufferObjectManager()){
    @Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {pTouchAreaLocalY);
    if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()){
        tsprite.setCurrentTileIndex(1);
    }
    else{
        tsprite.setCurrentTileIndex(0);
    }
    return true;
}
```

See this tutorial for more info: http://techtopz.in/2013/12/27/andengine-tiled-sprites-tutorial/

Comment: Where is the part we must insert our sprite file name ?

Comment: @YoshuaRudy as with any `sprite`, that part is done when initializing the `TextureRegion`. For example:
`tiledregion= BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "myTiledSprite.png", 1, 2);`
When "myTiledSprite.png" is the image file name. Take a look at the tutorials I pasted in my answer for a complete use case of `TiledSprite`, and/or search google for more info.